# Date Delimiter returning out of range results

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a pretty complex query.  Part of it is delimiting with a where statement and excluding results where the discharge date is greater than 90 days ago

date format in raw table is 2017-09-22

select for the values looks like the below

```
to_char("public".visit.visit_admit_date, 'MMDDYYYY') AS "Visit or Admit Date",
to_char("public".visit.visit_disch_date, 'MMDDYYYY') AS "Discharge Date",

WHERE

 exists ( SELECT distinct on ("public".visit.visit_id)  "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_code::text  
          FROM "public".visit 
          FULL OUTER JOIN "public".patient_procedure 
            ON "public".visit.visit_id = "public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num 
          FULL OUTER JOIN "public".procedure_desc_master_codes 
            ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_cpcode = "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id 
          FULL OUTER JOIN "public".procedure_group_cpt_code 
            ON "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_pdescm_id = "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id


GROUP BY "public".visit.visit_id, "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_code  
ORDER BY "public".visit.visit_id )

AND  "public".visit.visit_stay_type = '1' OR "public".visit.visit_stay_type ='2'
```

this last line being what i though would be the correct way to delimit by dates.

```
AND "public".visit.visit_disch_date > (now() - interval '90 day' )
```

I'm getting dates far out of range going back several years

if anyone needs to see more of the whole query I'll post it.  it's pretty big
also happy to include any more info anyone might request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `or`.  Use `in` instead:

```
 "public".visit.visit_stay_type IN ('1', '2') AND
 "public".visit.visit_disch_date > (now() - interval '90 day' )
```

Some other advice:

- Learn to use table aliases.
- `select distinct on` is not needed in an `exists` subquery.
- `order by` is almost never appropriate in a subquery.
- `full outer join` is rarely needed.

Comment: that worked!!! thank you, i probably would have never have found that I will remember that.  Did it create the problem because the date statement was only applying to one or the other?         oddly enough i have tried the query playing around with your other suggestions, but it mostly works as is.  the database i am working with is a hot pile.  i think this query is 300 lines long and has another 8 full outer joins outside of what you see here.

Comment: @JasonDossett . . . The date was only applying to the "2" value.

Comment: thanks!  once you point the error out it seems pretty obvious actually.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed that `IN` is better style than the `OR` here, but if you want to use `OR` in a future query (e.g. where `IN` is not appropriate because your `OR` would operate on different columns), you should use parentheses to group conditions like so:

```
AND (
  "public".visit.visit_stay_type = '1' 
  OR "public".visit.visit_stay_type ='2')
AND "public".visit.visit_disch_date > (now() - interval '90 day' )
```